# How to reassign result of concatenation in Julia?

Tags: julia

I need to create `Vector` of `Vector` of predefined structure in Julia. As of now I am trying to do it via iterative concatenation:

```
struct Scenario
    prob::Float64 # probability
    time::Float64   # duration of visit
    profit::Int64 # profit of visit
end

possible_times = [60, 90, 120, 150, 180]
scenarios = Scenario[]

for point in 1:num_points
    profit = rand(1:4)
    new_scenario = [Scenario(0.2, possible_times[i], profit) for i=1:5]
    scenarios = vcat(scenarios, new_scenario)
    
end
display(scenarios)
```

But I got the following

```
Warning: Assignment to `scenarios` in soft scope is ambiguous because a global variable by the same name exists: `scenarios` will be treated as a new local. Disambiguate by using `local scenarios` to suppress this warning or `global scenarios` to assign to the existing global variable.
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: scenarios not defined
```

So the first question is how to save the result of intermediate concatenation? And the second question is that way correct to achieve the goal? Or I do it wrong and there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally use `append!` instead of `vcat`:

```
for point in 1:num_points
    profit = rand(1:4)
    new_scenario = [Scenario(0.2, possible_times[i], profit) for i=1:5]
    append!(scenarios, new_scenario)
end
```

If you want to use `vcat` use the `global` keyword:

```
for point in 1:num_points
    profit = rand(1:4)
    new_scenario = [Scenario(0.2, possible_times[i], profit) for i=1:5]
    global scenarios = vcat(scenarios, new_scenario)
end
```

The point is that in `scenarios = vcat(scenarios, new_scenario)` you reassign the `scenarios` variable which is in global scope.

In general, the situation is a bit more complex (Julia behavior will depend on whether the code is run in interactive or non-interactive session), as you can read in [this section](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/#Local-Scope) of the Julia Manual (bullet 3 in this section on **Soft scope**). But if you do not want to dig into the details of scoping a simple and safe rule is: if you assign to a global variable then prefix the assignment operation with `global`.